# Statistics notations

Tags: statistics

I'm self teaching myself statistics and got stuck with notations; I'm working with multiple sources and notions seems to differ and confuse me a little, so I decided to write them down first.

$ \mu = $  mean of the population 
$ \sigma = $ std deviation of the population

$ \bar X = $ mean of the sample 
$ S = $ std deviation of the sample

$ \mu _ \bar X = \mu $ mean of the sample mean 
$ \sigma_ \bar X = \sigma / \sqrt n $ std deviation  of sample mean, aka mean standard error

It will be a silly question, but are all of these are correct? Are there any alternative notations for these?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ \mu = $  mean of the population 
$ \sigma = $ std deviation of the population

$\rho_{XY}=$ **population** correlation coefficient (between $X$ and $Y$)

$\sigma_{XY}=$ **population** covariance between $X$ and $Y$

$ \bar x = $ mean of the sample 
$ s = $ std deviation of the sample

$r_{XY}=$ sample correlation coefficient (between $X$ and $Y$).

$s_{XY}$= sample covariance between $X$ and $Y$

$\bar X$ is the (arithmetic) mean of a group of **random variables** (i.e.  $\bar 
X=\frac{X_1+X_2+...+X_n}{n}$). 
$\bar X$, itself, is a **random variable**.

$S$ is the standard deviation of a group of **random variables**.
$S:=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\bar X)^2}$
$S$,itself, is a random variable.

So, to conclude, we use Greek letters to denote the **population** (standard deviation, mean, whatever) and Roman letters to denote the **sample** (standard deviation, mean, whatever).
Capital letters, in statistics, usually denote **random variables**.

For a much-more-comprehensive list than this one, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_in_probability_and_statistics

Comment: What is the difference between X  and $ \bar X $ ?

Comment: $X$ is a random variable, following some distribution; $\bar X$ is also a random variable, following some distribution, but $\bar X$ is the *mean* of a load of random variables. i.e. $\bar X=\frac{X_1X_2+...+X_n}{n}$ where $X_1, ..., X_n$ are random variables.

Comment: One last thing, is there any difference between $ \bar x $ and $ \bar X $ ?

Comment: Sure. $\bar x$ is the sample mean (or just the mean). It's just a number.  e.g. for $1,2,3$, $\bar x=2$. $\bar X$ is a random variable; it's the mean, yes, but of random variables, not numbers. So, if we've got random variables $X,Y,Z$, then $\bar X=\frac{X+Y+Z}{3}$.

Comment: does the same relationship applies s and S for std dev?

Comment: Yep- exactly. $S$ is just the standard deviation of a load of random variables. You might see it written as $S=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}[\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2-n \bar X^2]}$

Comment: and what about $ \mu _ \bar X = \mu $  and 
$ \sigma_ \bar X = \sigma / \sqrt n $ , since you omitted them in the answer, are they incorrect notations?

Comment: @Kartopukus Yeah- they're also correct. Some alternative notations include writing $\mu_{\bar X}=E[\bar X]$ and $\sigma_{\bar X}^2=Var[\bar X]$, but that's just a matter of personal preference on the writer's part.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, thanks to you I'm now able to understand the main idea clearly.

Comment: Sure. I was pretty much in the same position as you when starting statistics, as the notation, more than anything, can throw people off. Once you get your head around the notation, it's a lot easier! If you've any more questions, just comment below.